# Bootstrap validator throwing 'BootstrapValidator's JavaScript requires jQuery '

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, webforms

I am building a simple web forms web application and I want to use the [bootstrap validator plugin](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) for validation. I am not a big jQuery fan so I use the data annotations.

I included the needed CSS file in the bundle.config

```
<include path="~/Content/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />
```

I registered the jquery and the validator script in BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/validator").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrapValidator.min.js"));
```

And I rendered the scripts in the master page:

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/validator") %>
```

I registered the feedback icons in the main form that way they're always there:

```
<form runat="server" data-bv-feedbackicons-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-bv-feedbackicons-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-bv-feedbackicons-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">
```

This is the form I'm trying to validate. It's the login form that VS2013 generates, but I stripped it down to fit my needs.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right text-middle col-md-5">
                    Username:
                </td>
                <td class="text-middle">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Username" CssClass="form-control" data-bv-notempty="true"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-right text-middle col-md-5">
                    Password:
                </td>
                <td class="text-middle">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" data-bv-notempty="true"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="LogIn" Text="Log in" CssClass="btn btn-primary col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"/>
```

When I click the button, no validation is done and I get the server-validation error that the user field is empty. For some reason the client-side validation never happens.

Edit:
I forgot the javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form').bootstrapValidator();
    });
</script>
```

Side question, will this work if I put this code in the master page, or do I have to put this on all the pages I want validation?

**EDIT:**

I swapped the includes and made the change above as well, but it still doesn't work. Now when the bootstrapValidator function is called, this exception gets thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
(anonymous function) 
fire 
self.fireWith 
jQuery.extend.ready 
completed
```

And still no client-side validation what so ever...

Comment: Did JQuery included first ?
If no, you should include it first then bootstrapValidator js.

Comment: I made the changes but still no luck, I updated the question

Comment: You have to debug your code to see which line throws this exception.

Comment: there is only one javascript line in the code and that's the one that throws the exception -  ` $('form').bootstrapValidator();`

Comment: Looks like the bootstrapValidator js is not included, please check that.

Comment: It's there, first is jQuery and then the validator, both minified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62523/discussion-between-gregoryhousemd-and-arkni).

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve this problem? If yes, how?

Comment: I migrated the project to MVC + AngularJS  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me point out that sure you included jQuery, but make sure you include it before the functions that need it. You use your script bundle to include the validator on the page before jQuery is included. This will make it fail. Try doing:

```
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>
<%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/validator") %>
```

Order is always important when including libraries. Always include jQuery first, then any libraries that make use of it.

Comment: I just added an edit to the question, it solved the exception, but still it doesn't work